# wait until element not found or hidden

Tags: java, selenium

I want to wait my thread until the element is not present or hidden. Trying code like this

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TIME_OUT_SECS).until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                    return !d.findElement(by).isDisplayed();
                }
            });
```

but getting error

```
attempting to use incompatible return type
```

Answer (score 1):

May be just an autoboxing fail - did you try to change

```
return !d.findElement(by).isDisplayed();
```

to

```
return (Boolean)!d.findElement(by).isDisplayed();
```

? As isDisplayed returns `boolean` but you actually need `Boolean` it **should** be autoboxed, but regarding autoboxing you never know.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're using the typing for ExpectedCondition incorrectly here:

```
new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>()
```

This should create a class with a method

```
public WebElement apply(WebDriver arg0) {}
```

As you can see, the expected return type of apply() is the class passed into the type parameter.

You probably want to do:

```
new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>()
```